# How much data do I need to build a classification model?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, dataset

While studying a machine learning based classification model, I started wondering how much I need to build a classification model. The way I do is that I download some specific dataset within a certain time period, do some preprocessing and feed those data into the model but I am not sure if I am doing it properly. The way I think is I can never that the right size of dataset for the classification but I can only update the model as more data are available.

So, my questions are the following:
when building a classification model

- How much data do I need?
- How should I choose the target data for the classification model?

  - Are the recent ones better?
  - Data a year ago is too old for the current model?

How do you choose the data and what size of dataset do you start?

Answer (score 1):

> How much data do I need?

It depends (this is a popular answer in data science).  If I recall correctly, you need upwards of 400 observations to estimate the intercept of a logistic regression to within a margin of error of 0.1.  That should serve as a baseline.  Any less than this, and the baseline for a very simple model may have a margin of error too big to accept.

> How should I choose the target data for the classification model?

It depends (surprise!).  Data From a year ago may be OK depending on the context.  But it all depends on the context.

> How do you choose the data and what size of data set do you start?

If all goes well, I do not choose the data.  Rather, I select some time frame over which to collect data and that just happens to be the sample, be it balanced or imbalanced.  The size of the data may depend on a power calculation, but again it depends on how the study was conducted and if I had control over data collection or not.

Answer (score 1):

So the amount of data you will need depends on how much variation you have in your data. I will give a silly classification problem to illustrate this:

Say you want to classify people who eat meat and people who don't eat meat based on data you have on what food your subjects eat every day. For illustrating the idea of variation in data, consider two cases:

Case 1): All meat-eaters eat meat every day and all vegetarians never eat meat.

Case 2): Meat-eaters mostly eat meat once or twice a week and all vegetarians never eat meat.

If case 1 is how your subjects behave, your classification model essentially needs like one day of data to perform a near-perfect classification (whether your chosen model can function under low data is a different question).

If case 2 is how people are, you will need at least 7 days of data to make a good classification model. So like Demetri Pananos said, it depends.

I don't think there is a magic number of sample points above which all our statistical problems are sorted (like the magic sample size of 30 data points used by biologists). You have to decide it based on how much variation is there in your data. Since you are not intending to do some sort of hypothesis testing (I am assuming), you can take some arbitrary amount of data, see if it gives a good fit and if not try with some more.

Now to answer your second question of data a year ago is bad, consider the same example:

How long do you think people might take on an average to change their meat-based diet to completely meat-free or vice versa? It is very likely someone who is a meat-eater today was a meat-eater yesterday and two weeks ago. But it might not be a great idea to predict whether someone is a  meat-eater based on data on what he ate ten years ago. So think about a reasonable timeframe in which your data can vary.

I hope that helps. I am pretty new to this field so I might have some shortcomings in my understanding. Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.